# php each 1 and 8 element in 2 iterations

Tags: php

I have a loop. I need write to 1 and 8 element a button. How I can do it?

```
$cnt = 1;

while($r = $now->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($cnt > 6) {
        break; //write only 5 elements to 1 iteration
    }
   if($cnt === 1 || $cnt === 8) { //not working
       echo "<button>Send</button>"; 
   }

   $cnt++;
}
```

My condition is now working. How I can do correctly condition to 8 element, which  in 2 iterations?

Example, waht I want get: 
------Button-------
1) record 
2) record 
3) record 
4) record 
5) record 
1) record 
2) record 
3) record 
------Button-------
1) record 
2) record 
....

Comment: __Increase__ `$cnt`

Comment: Sorry. I have `$cnt++` not working..

Comment: your $cnt will not reach at 8 you are breaking the loop at 7

Comment: I need break each 5 element. I want write each 5 elements to page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I understand your question wrong, but I think that this should achieve it.

```
$i = 1;
$j = 1;

while($r = $now->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($i > 6) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    if($j === 1 || $j%8 === 0) {
        echo "<button>Send</button>"; 
    }

   $i++;
   $j++;
}
```